# What else should I have put in this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, quality-improvement

My question [Why is it adding a horizontal scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76088168/why-is-it-adding-a-horizontal-scroll-bar) was answered, but I need guidance about how I asked it.

What else should I have provided? I couldn't provide all the ancillary files because there are 108 of them. I couldn't reduce it down because the DevExpress elements were almost certainly the cause of this (they were) and so I couldn't create a simple example.

What should I have done differently in this question?

Comment: _"This question is answered. ..."_ So well, why bother? The single DV (atm)? (Beware of the _Meta Effect_!)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because the question was closed for not meeting guidelines. I want to learn how to avoid that in the future.

Comment: "_I couldn't reduce it down because the DevExpress elements were almost certainly the cause of this (they were) and so I couldn't create a simple example._" Can you not create a small example where you say I have used these DevExpress elements and let DevExpress SMEs try answering?

Comment: I see you had received some feedback on your question to mention the frameworks you used and to add the devexpress tag. Why haven't you done that yet? People without subject matter expertise (saying since I don't have expertise on this either) wouldn't know what the `dxbl-form-layout-item` element is supposed to be.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Good point on adding the DevExpress tag. I didn't because by the time that was suggested, the question had been closed. Would that addition have kept the question open?

Comment: Potentially yes, tags are what connects SME's to questions, so if you had added that tag your question might have received attention from people who actually know DevExpress. HTML, CSS, etc. tags are much wider and many people following these tags might not know about it. This is why mentioning the tools / languages used is very important when asking a question.

Comment: If you aren't aware about it, you can submit your question for review after editing it, which will send it to the review queues where other users can review and reopen your question.

Comment: @DavidThielen - Impossible to know the answer to that question, however, that would be an improvement to the question.  I wouldn't pass up the opportunity to mention the frameworks. In this case you could have created a MRE, somebody actually did that for you, in order to answer your question. I would go ahead and provide any appropriate improvements to your question in order to potentially have it reopened.

Comment: @SecurityHound Actually that MRE didn't demonstrate the problem. But in the course of writing it, the individual did find the issue.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I did submit it for review after editing it but it stayed closed. That's why I asked here.

Comment: @DavidThielen - Did you allow the question to be reviewed?  There are hundreds of questions in the queue of questions that can be potentially be reopened. It takes awhile to review that amount of questions.

Comment: @SecurityHound I waited 3 days - is that long enough? I guess you never know for sure as there's no notification of if it's been reviewed.

Comment: @DavidThielen - The question wasn't closed 3 days ago, it was closed, yesterday (~09:00 Zulu). It was edited yesterday (~16:00 Zulu) and reopened today.  This means it took less than 24 hours to be reopened.

Comment: Which is pretty good, all things considered. Usually reopens languish for quite a while.

Comment: @SecurityHound you’re right and I’m sorry. It started with my posting it earlier, getting it closed, then trying again. And I conflated all the time across this. Sorry, I shouldn’t have.

Comment: The fact that the answer you got starts with "Okay, I've been able to create a possible minimal reproducible example:", and then shows **five** lines of HTML, should answer the Meta question for you. The problem is not what is missing; the problem is what you have failed to take away. In order to know what to take away, you should [study](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem first in order to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) it. It is not the purpose of Stack Overflow to *find* the bug, but to *explain* it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That MRE in the answer did not reproduce the problem. It identified where the individual thought the issue was (it wasn't), but in the rest of his answer he did help identify the issue.